# What percentage of neutrinos does the earth absorb?

Tags: earth, neutrinos, absorption

Assuming a neutrino beam is directed from a point on the surface of the earth to its antipode, what percentage of neutrinos will emerge on the other side?

Comment: Neutrino cross-sections go [up with energy](https://icecube.wisc.edu/news/press-releases/2017/11/first-look-at-how-earth-stops-high-energy-neutrinos-in-their-tracks/).

Comment: Almost all pass through unimpeded. [What is the DUNE experiment?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2os1rfVXRCM)